# What is the meaning associated to a baseball and a screw?

Tags: idioms

In some cartoons (*Tom & Jerry* and *The Looney Toons*, if I remember correctly), I've seen the image of what seemed to be a baseball or softball along with a screw in a balloon.

If I recall correctly, the balloon appeared near a character who had just been "screwed" by someone else. Even if I can obviously tie the screw to the pun, I wonder how the ball is involved.

Comment: I cannot figure out what image you're trying to construct. But is this even a question about English language?

Comment: @tenfour: What other StackExchange site would you suggest? :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a reference to *[screwball](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/screwball?region=us)*:

> **screwball** |ˈskruˈbɔl|
>   noun
>   **1** *Baseball* a pitched ball that moves in a direction opposite to that of a curveball.
>   **2** *informal* a crazy or eccentric person.
>
> adjective  *informal*
>   crazy; absurd.
>   • relating to or denoting a style of fast-moving comedy film involving eccentric characters or ridiculous situations.

[image: screwball image]

Comment: +1. Also worth mentioning that comedies, and sometimes people are occasionally referred to as `screwball` (as implied by defintion 2 above).

Comment: As my eye was scanning down the page, I went "screw... ball... Oh, screwball!" right before I saw your answer. Gave me a bit of a chuckle.

Comment: Sorry for being late. You found one of the images I had in my memory. :) Thank you for your answer. I think it really makes sense only in the context of English language.